Count number of rows in grouped column in Pandas
I have a simple dataset and I am trying to group a column by its values and create a new column that contains how many rows are returned for that group.
I have tried several options but nothing seems to work.
A simple (not working) example could be like this:
import pandas as pd
data = {'Team' : ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3','3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Count'] = df.groupby('Team')['Team'].count()
print(df)

I also came across options like .size() and .valuecounts(), but nothing works.
My desired output would be like this:
import pandas as pd
data = {'Team' : ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3','3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3'],
        'Count' : [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)


You need to merge the count dataframe with the original dataframe to get the result you want.

Could you give me a code example please?

Sorry, what's the question? You already know how to do the part in the title. Please [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask].

I've closed the question based on what I assume you meant to ask. LMK if not.
